# Macbook EFI parition after reFind

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, efi

I have a question about what should be located in the EFI partition of my macbook. A couple of years ago I dual booted ubuntu with reFind, however recently I erased my main partition to clean up my mac. Now I would like to dual boot arch also using reFind, so I mounted my EFI partition and found this:

```
BOOTLOG
BOOTLOG.OLD
screenshot__001.bmp
screenshot__002.bmp
EFI/
    APPLE/ 
        CACHES/
            CAFEBEEF/
                (empty)
        EXTENSIONS/
            Firmware.scap
        FIRMWARE/
            MBP91_00D3_B0D_LOCKED.scap
    Ubuntu/
    tools/
        gptsync_x64.efi     
    reFind/
```

So I deleted the ubuntu and reFind directories since I want to start with a fresh install of reFind. My question is were the files contained in the APPLE and tools directories created from the old reFind install, in which case I can delete them, or are they integral to the standard mac boot process (so I shouldn't mess with them)?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete everything from the EFI partition if you wish. OS X will recreate what it needs when the operating system starts. Basically, OS X copies the `Firmware.scap` file from the boot partition to the EFI  partition.

The files and folders marked below for deletion are not part of OS X.

```
BOOTLOG                            <---- Delete
BOOTLOG.OLD                        <---- Delete
screenshot__001.bmp                <---- Delete
screenshot__002.bmp                <---- Delete
EFI/
    APPLE/ 
        CACHES/
            CAFEBEEF/
                (empty)
        EXTENSIONS/
            Firmware.scap
        FIRMWARE/
            MBP91_00D3_B0D_LOCKED.scap
    Ubuntu/                             <---- Delete (Part of Ubuntu)
    tools/                              <---- Delete (Part of rEFInd)
        gptsync_x64.efi                 <---- Delete (Part of rEFInd)
    reFind/                             <---- Delete (Part of rEFInd)
```

The rest of the files were put there by OS X or related software.